# reading mail sequentially in mail-listener 2 node library

Tags: javascript, node.js, listener

is there a property to set that enables to read mail sequentially in mail-listener2 module ,so that one can perform set of operation on after reading one mail and then move on to next .

what i can think of is we can change these property

```
 searchFilter:
 fetchUnreadOnStart:true
```

or use seq no in any way

```
mailListener.on("mail", function(mail, seqno, attributes){
// do something with mail object including attachments
console.log("emailParsed", mail);
// mail processing code goes here
});
```

how could i get this done

Comment: well i got the answer , but since its easy won't write in answer section ,             r\the listeners read each mail according to sequence number and as each mail coming in inbox will have sequence number it reads it sequentially , all you need to do is write your required function inside this code                                   mailListener.on("mail", function(mail, seqno, attributes){
// do something with mail object including attachments
console.log("emailParsed", mail);
my function();
});     [refer to mail listener 2 ](https://github.com/chirag04)